# How to send welcome email once user buys the subscription

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, subscription

I have working on the functionality where I need to send welcome mail to user once he purchases the subscription . I am implementing the above functionality using woocommerce subscription plugin.

So kindly let me know how can I implement the above?

Comment: Hook [woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/#woocommerce_checkout_subscription_created) and generate the email there? And possibly some of the renewal ones as well?

Comment: We used the plugin AutomatWoo for these notifications